# Update database value onclick with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am trying to get this to work so that when I click on the plus sign in the HTML table (the input tag), my database will be updated according to the tr that the button is in. My code is currently not working this way; how can I get the input button to update the database upon clicking?

My second question is how can I get this to work for more than one city? Is there a way to incorporate every city into a single chunk of PHP code to update the database, and if so, how? Thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
<form action="all_records.php" method="post">
    <td name="albuquerque" class="albuquerque">
        <b>Albuquerque</b>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" name="button1" value="+" id="1">
    </td>
</form>

<form action="all_records.php" method="post">
    <td name="atlanta" class="atlanta">
        <b>Atlanta</b>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" name="button2" value="+" id="2">
    </td>
</form>
```

all_records.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;


$DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
$DATABASE_USER = 'root';
$DATABASE_PASS = '';
$DATABASE_NAME = 'user_database';


$con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    exit('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}


if(isset($_POST['button1'])) { 
    $city = $_POST['albuquerque'];

    $edit_city = mysqli_query($user_database,"update test_cities set action='+' where city='$city'");
    header("location:cities.php");

}
?>
```

Comment: You have multiple forms so you don't need to have different names for the buttons or fields. Add a hidden field in your form for the city name.

Comment: Using `submit` buttons like this will refresh the whole page every time a button is clicked. It's cumbersome and slow. Think about using a click handler to send an AJAX request on a click.

Comment: Also, when you are done getting this to work, discard it completely and use PHP PDO instead.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you are doing with the `update test_cities set action='+' where...` but consider using the primary key of your test_cities table to identify each record.  Maybe something like the following:

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=user_database;host=localhost', 'root', 'xxx');
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']==='GET') {
    $cites = $pdo->query('SELECT id, name, bla FROM test_cities')->fetchAll();
    $rows=[];
    foreach($cities as $city) {
        $rows[] = "<tr><td><b>$city[name]</b></td><td class='add-row' data-id='$city[id]'>+</td>";
    }
    echo(getYourHtmlPage($rows);
}
else {
    $pdo->prepare('UPDATE test_cities SET some_property=? WHERE id=?')->execute($_POST['some_property'], $_POST['id']);
}
```

Then, you will not be submitting the page but just sending an ajax request.

```
document.getElementById("add-row").addEventListener("click", function() {
    const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("POST", 'all_records.php');
    req.send("id="+this.dataset.id);
    req.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
      // update as needed
    }
});
```

You might also want to consider using a form with checkboxes and then update all of the submitted cities (use name `city[]` so they will be send as an array).

PS.  None of the above was tested.